# How to parse date and float data type from excel file using Angular?

Tags: angular, excel, angularjs, dataframe

I am trying to **get data types from excel row cells**. Primarily there are 4 datatypes present, **date**, **string**, **number** and **float**. I can parse the **string** and **number** data types successfully but I cannot do the same for **date** and **float** values.

Whenever I try to **parse date** data type, (for eg **21-12-2022**) the code instead of reading it as it is (i.e. **21-12-2022**), instead reads it as some **arbitrary number**(for eg **44907**) as shown in the image and hence parses it as a **number**. I don't know why this is happening and hence I **cannot parse date data types**. I have attached a screenshot for your reference!

Another issue is that **float data types are not getting parsed correctly**. The function **parses them as numbers** instead of **float** as shown in the image. As shown the float **110.9** in the image is getting parsed as **number instead of float**!

This is the demo table:

| VDist date | VCHR Dt-Year | Vendor Name | VDIST unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-12-2022 | 2015 | xyz | 110.9 |
| NaN | 13-12-2022 | 2016 | abc |

This is the code I am using:

```
onFileChange(evt: any) {

    /* wire up file reader */

    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>evt.target;

    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');

    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {

      /* read workbook */

      const bstr: string = e.target.result;

      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });



      /* grab first sheet */

      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];

      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];



      /* save data */

      this.data = <AOA>XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1, raw: true });

      console.log(this.data);

    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);

  }
```

Screenshot for your reference:
[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

It's not an arbitrary number. Excel stores dates as days since 1/1/1900.

By plugging your example number of 44907 into a cell in Excel and formatting it to a date, it says it's the 12th December 2022 (not 21st as in your example...).

So no, you won't be able to precisely tell that it's a Date field vs a number field. You could assume that 5-digit numbers are dates, but that's not particularly great.

Not really a way round it that I can think of for you...

Not sure I understand about the float issue, however. JS/TS don't have a float type, only a number type which encapsulates both.

You would have to do your own checking, I guess, by turning it into a string and looking for a `.` character to determine if it's a float vs int. Probably a better way to do it than that but Google is over there, go nuts.

Not the best answer you're looking for, I'm afraid, but those are likely the limits of what you can do with JS/TS types.